# Spline interpolation of flow series from quarterly to monthly

Tags: r, spline

I want to replicate the results of a paper and the authors mention that they spline interpolate a series of quarterly capital flows to obtain a monthly series.

I tried this with the `spline` function in R but I am not satisfied with the result. Since I have a quarterly **flow** series I do not want to end up with a monthly series which "moves between" the quarterly entries, where one month is equal to the entry for the quarter. The monthly series should rather "sum" up to the quarterly series, such that the sum over 3 months fit the actual data for the corresponding quarter.

But this is not what I am ending up, with using the following code:

```
    # example data
flows <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), length.out = 20, by="quarter"),
                               capital_flows = 1000*rnorm(n=20, mean=1, 
                                                    sd=3))


# monthly series
monthly = seq(flows$date[1], tail(flows$date,1), by="month")

# interpolate to monthly series
flows_interpolated = data.frame(date= monthly,
                                capital_flows_interpolated = spline(flows, method="fmm",
                                                                    xout=monthly)$y)
```

Thankful for any comments on how to change the code.. It seems that maybe the `approx` command would be the way to go, but since the authors write about spline interpolation this is probably not how they did it (or I miss something).

PS: I am aware of the `tempdisagg` package and I think it is very useful! but since the authors of the original paper are talking about spline interpolation I wanted to ask if it is also possible with `spline`

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add the interpolated steps (monthly increments/decrements) rather than the interpolated absolute values to have those deltas *sum up* to the quarterly difference?